Заставить переадресацию делать с 301 кодом, вместо 307
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

Достаточно долго мучаюсь с этим, никак решение не найду.
Переадресацию с протокола http на https, происходит с 307 кодом. Что говорит поисковым роботам о временно перемещенной странице. Я пытаюсь сделать ее с 301 кодом и сообщить поисковым ботам, что страница перемещена окончательно...
Как это можно поправить?
